# Conector do MySQL para Python 3

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, python, django, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um projeto com Django e Python 3 mas não consigo achar o conector do MySQL apropriado. O `django.db.backends.mysql` funciona, mas apenas para Python 2, e eu queria evitar usar essa versão. No terminal quando eu digito `import django.db.backends.mysql` ele importa sem erro algum, mas quando eu vou rodar no servidor pelo comando `python3 manage.py runserver` aparece o erro:

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 18, in 
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tem como resolver isso? Projetos Django possuem alguma restrição quanto ao desenvolvimento utilizando Python 3?

Atualmente o ambiente de desenvolvimento está em um OS X Yosemite.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente este é um problema clássico deste plugin em especial.

Usando o `pip`, execute o seguinte:

```
pip install --allow-all-external mysql-connector-python
```

Ajuste seu arquivo `settings.py` para o seguinte:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    }
}
```

[Tirei a resposta daqui](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com.br/2014/09/django-with-python-3-and-mysql-database.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano. Funcionou corretamente depois da sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema semelhante, depois de muita pesquisa vi que precisava instalar dos dependências no sistema:

```
   sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
   sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Tirei os detalhes daqui: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/